# SSH server started with a system account not accepting connections

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd

I started a new SSH daemon with a config file with a non-standard port number. Now if I start the SSHD as sudo I can SSH onto the host but if i start as a different system account, the daemon starts but the connections fail. Does the SSHD always need to be started as root ?

I made sure the SSHD is running, it just doesnt accept connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not practical to run `sshd` as non-root. `sshd` needs `root` privileges for

- password authentication (only `root` can access `/etc/shadow`)
- binding to a port that is below 1024
- calling `setuid()` in order to obtain the privileges of the user that has connected

If you use an unprivileged port and key-based only auth, you may be able to make it work, but you'll be restricted to connections with the user that is running `sshd`.

There is a relevant discussion here: http://seclists.org/basics/2003/Aug/564

Answer (score 0):

Which port did you use? Ports below 1024 are privileged to Root only.

Comment: I used port 7100, i can start the SSHD if i run the command as root, its only when i start it with another account it has this behavior.